# `git commit` is stuck on macOS Ventura

Tags: xcode, git

Today I woke up and realised I cannot `commit` anymore... Strangely enough other `git` commands work fine. Whenever I create a new directory, `git init .` inside, `touch` a new, empty file inside, `git add` it, and then run `git commit -am "test"` the command gets stuck. I wait for 10 minutes and nothing happens...

My OS version: macOS 13.4.1; MacBook Pro 2017.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)

$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

I have been googling around a little and tried two other `git` installations: the one from Homebrew installed with `brew install git` and the one from Conda installed with `conda install -c conda-forge git`. No luck. I have reinstalled my XCode Command line Tools with first removing them and then `xcode-select --install` (~15GB download and 10min installation). No luck.

Did anyone else experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out my problem is not Mac related at all, `gpg` commit signing gets stuck.
See the following questions for resource:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382279/gpg-hangs-when-private-keys-are-accessed
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52444915/git-gpg-signing-fails-without-a-clear-message
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769831/how-to-make-gpg-prompt-for-passphrase-on-cli

In order to debug try command: `GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -am "new file"`